# Error while passing view model to view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My view looks something like this:

```cs
@model SystemBase.Domain.ViewModel.SelfDeclarationReportViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "testi";
    Layout = "~/Areas/AdminAgency/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

I want to pass some data of a declared view model class to my view using this code:

```cs
public ActionResult Index(Guid companyID, Guid periodID, EvaluationType evaluationType)
{
    try
    {
        var form = _FormsService.GetMandatory(companyID, 
            periodID, EvaluationType.Mandatory);
        var userForm = _UserFormService.GetMandatoryWithSelfDeclarationScores(
            User.UserID().Value, companyID, periodID);

        if (userForm == null)
        {
            userForm = _UserFormService.CreateMandatoryUserForm(form, 
                companyID, User.UserID().Value);
        }

        var m = new SelfDeclarationReportViewModel();
        m.Form = form;
        m.Userform = userForm;

        return View(m);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

In debugging mode, everything seems ok and the breakpoints work in both view and controller, but the output is an error with this message

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'SystemBase.Domain.ViewModel.SelfDeclarationReportViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SystemBase.Domain.ViewModel.OrganizationViewModel'.

Comment: Something is wrong in the view, further away. There's a dictionary handled incorrectly. No code provided to check this out.

Comment: I would look for all usages of `OrganizationViewModel` and see if you can identify which occurrence is the issue.

Comment: OT - your `catch` block is very bad. NEVER use `throw ex`, even for testing. By doing so, you truncate the stack trace. Use `throw` instead, which rethrows the exception as is, but still enables you to set a breakpoint and examine the exception if required.

Comment: @jmcilhinney
all of `OrganizationViewModel` usages
https://file.io/P4HEOaWBWrfZ

Comment: Can you show a full view, pls?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the return one return view which belong to the Index View

Index.cshtml

```
            try
            {
                var studentViewModel = new StudentViewModel();
                
                return View(studentViewModel);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            return View();        //here you need to return something other wise you get an error
```